# Big code... for you!

Tags: code-golf

At the opening scene of the *Dark Knight rises*, there is a rather [awkward dialogue](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/baneposting) between a CIA agent and the villain Bane.

> **CIA agent:** “If I pull that [mask] off, will you die?”
>
> **Bane:** “It would be extremely painful…”
>
> **CIA agent:** “You’re a big guy.”
>
> **Bane:** “…for you.”

It’s unsure if Bane intends to say “painful for you” or “big guy for you”. Let’s settle this problem once for all through code golfing!

### Challenge

Your task is write a program that reorders the above dialogue depending on an integer given as input.

CIA agent dialogue words are:
`If` `I` `pull` `that` `off` `will` `you` `die?` `You're` `a` `big` `guy.`

Bane’s dialogue words are:
`It` `would` `be` `extremely` `painful...` `for` `you!`

Please note that `die?`, `You’re`, `painful...` and `you!` are considered as single words.

1. Given an integer n as input, convert it to binary
2. Reading the binary digits from left to right, output the next word from CIA agent dialogue if the digit is `1`, and the next word from Bane dialogue if the digit is `0`. The words should be separated by a space.
   When the speaker changes, add a line feed. Also, prefix each dialogue line with the speaker name (`BANE:`  or `CIA:` ).

You can assume that the input always starts with a 1 in binary form, and has 12 ones and 7 zeroes.

### Example

`522300`

1. Converted to binary: `1111111100000111100`
2. The number starts with 8 ones, so we output the 8 first words from CIA’s agent dialogue, and prefix them with CIA:
   `CIA: If I pull that off will you die?`
3. Then we got 5 zeroes, so we get the 5 first words from Bane’s dialogue:
   `BANE: It would be extremely painful...`
4. Then there are 4 ones, so we output the 4 next CIA words:
   `CIA: You’re a big guy.`
5. Then 2 zeroes:
   `BANE: for you!`

**Final result:**

```
CIA: If I pull that off will you die?
BANE: It would be extremely painful...
CIA: You’re a big guy.
BANE: for you!
```

### More test cases:

**494542**

```
CIA: If I pull that
BANE: It would be
CIA: off
BANE: extremely
CIA: will you die? You're
BANE: painful... for
CIA: a big guy.
BANE: you!
```

**326711**

```
CIA: If
BANE: It would
CIA: I pull that off will you
BANE: be extremely painful... for
CIA: die? You're
BANE: you!
CIA: a big guy.
```

Comment: Can each line end in a space?

Comment: @xnor Yes, that's ok.

Comment: "that" and "it" as first word of Bane's speech don't line up in test cases/quote

Comment: @Mistah fixed to "it", thanks!

Comment: Is a leading newline allowed?

Comment: @user63956 no, it should start with the CIA agent sentence. newline or no newline is allowed at the end.

Comment: Is it just me or someone read the dialogue in bane's voice.

Comment: "It’s unsure if Bane intends to say “painful for you” or “big guy for you”" 
Actually... https://i.imgur.com/ZRA76Af.jpg

Comment: @SomeGuy Maybe you're unsure, but it's pretty clear that "painful for you" is most likely the intended meaning. "Big guy for you" hardly makes sense grammatically.

Comment: When I  watched the film, I didn't put ellipses after Bane's "it would be extremely painful." Neither does [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Dark-Knight-Rises,-The.html). So I wonder, why did you?

Comment: @theonlygusti I took the dialogue from [knowyourmeme.com](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/baneposting) - there is a whole article on this important topic :-)

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth - 138 bytes

I should look into compressing the movie script.

```
K_cc"guy big a You're die? you will off that pull I If you! for painful... extremely be would That"d12jmj;++@c"BANECIA"4ed\:m.)@Kedhdr8jQ2
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K_cc%22guy+big+a+You%27re+die%3F+you+will+off+that+pull+I+If+you%21+for+painful...+extremely+be+would+That%22d12jmj%3B%2B%2B%40c%22BANECIA%224ed%5C%3Am.%29%40Kedhdr8jQ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=522300%0A494542%0A326711&debug=0).

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>203</s> 201 bytes

*Edit: saved 2 bytes by shamelessly borrowing the `trim()` idea from [ETHproductions answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109036/58563)*

```js
n=>"If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy. It would be extremely painful... for you!".split` `.map((_,i,a)=>[`
BANE: `,`
CIA: `,' '][j^(j=n>>18-i&1)?j:2]+a[k[j]++],k=[j=12,0]).join``.trim()
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>"If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy. It would be extremely painful... for you!".split` `.map((_,i,a)=>[`
BANE: `,`
CIA: `,' '][j^(j=n>>18-i&1)?j:2]+a[k[j]++],k=[j=12,0]).join``.trim()

console.log(f(522300))
console.log(f(494542))
console.log(f(326711))
```

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>209</s> <s>202</s> 201 bytes

```
(n,a="It would be extremely painful... for you! If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.".split` `,b=[6,18])=>(F=(s,p=n%2)=>n?F((p^(n>>=1)%2?p?`
CIA: `:`
BANE: `:` `)+a[b[p]--]+s):s.trim())``
```

Old approach:

```
(n,a="If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy. It would be extremely painful... for you!".split` `,b=[12,0])=>(F=p=>p^n%2?F(n%2)+(p?`
CIA:`:`
BANE:`):n?F(p,n>>=1)+" "+a[b[p]++]:``)(n%2).trim()
```

#### Test snippet

```js
f=(n,a="It would be extremely painful... for you! If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.".split` `,b=[6,18])=>(F=(s,p=n%2)=>n?F((p^(n>>=1)%2?p?`
CIA: `:`
BANE: `:` `)+a[b[p]--]+s):s.trim())``

console.log(f(522300))
console.log(f(494542))
console.log(f(326711))
```

Comment: I'm shamelessly borrowing your `trim()` idea. I was sure there was something better than `slice(1)` but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Arnauld Fine with me, now we're all tied up. I bet there's a way to do it in under 200 :-)

Answer (score 6):

### C++11 (GCC), <s>298</s> 293 bytes

```cpp
#include<sstream>
[](int i){std::stringstream b("It would be extremely painful... for you!"),c("If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.");std::string s,w;int n=0,t=i,p;while(t/=2)n++;for(;n>=0;p=t)((t=i>>n&1)?c:b)>>w,s+=p^t?t?"CIA: ":"BANE: ":" ",s+=t^(i>>--n)&1?w+"\n":w;return s;}
```

A lambda function that takes an integer and returns the dialogue as a `std::string`. You can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/b6uunu).

Ungolfed version (with some explanation):

```cpp
#include<sstream>

[](int i) {
    std::stringstream bane("It would be extremely painful... for you!"),
                      cia("If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.");
    std::string s, w;
    int n = 0, t = i, p;
    // Find the position of the most significant bit (n)
    while (t/=2) n++;

    for (; n>=0; p=t) {
        t = i>>n&1; // Current bit
        // Append the speaker name if the previous bit was different
        if (t != p) s += (t ? "CIA: " : "BANE: ");
        else s += " ";

        // Read the next word from one of the streams
        if (t) cia >> w;
        else bane >> w;

        s += w;

        if (t != ((i>>--n)&1)) // Append a newline if the next bit is different
            s += "\n";
    }

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>252 227</s> 226 bytes

```
n=>[...n.toString(2,b="If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.".split` `,c="It would be extremely painful... for you!".split` `)].map((a,i,j)=>(a!=j[i-1]?+a?i?`
CIA: `:`CIA: `:`
BANE: `:``)+(+a?b:c).shift()).join` `
```

## Usage

```
f=n=>[...n.toString(2,b="If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.".split` `,c="It would be extremely painful... for you!".split` `)].map((a,i,j)=>(a!=j[i-1]?+a?i?`
CIA: `:`CIA: `:`
BANE: `:``)+(+a?b:c).shift()).join` `
f(522300)
```

## Notes

This is golfing-in-progress, I think I can still shave off some bytes, but feel free to leave suggestions in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.6, 232 bytes

```py
from itertools import*
c="you! for painful... extremely be would It".split(),"guy. big a You're die? you will off that pull I If".split()
for n,r in groupby(f'{int(input()):b}',int):
 print("BCAINAE::"[n::2],*[c[n].pop()for _ in r])
```

**Edit**, equivalently:

```py
from itertools import*
c="It would be extremely painful... for you!".split(),"_ If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.".split()
for n,r in groupby(map(int,f'{int(input()):b}')):
 print("BCAINAE::"[n::2],*map(c[n].pop,r))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 121 bytes

```
A=[`It Ùd ¼ extÚ+ pafª... f y!`¸`If I pªl È     f Øi y ¹e? Y' a big guy.`¸]¢®^T?["
BANE:""
CIA:"]gT=Z :P +S+AgZ vÃx
```

Contains many unprintables, so you'd just be better off [testing it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=QT1bYEl0INkCZCC8IGV4dJzaKyBwYYhmqi4uLiBmjiB5jCFguGBJZiBJIHCqbCDICSCPZiDYaSB5jCC5ZT8gWYwnnCBhIGJpZyBndXkuYLhdoq5eVD9bIgpCQU5FOiIiCkNJQToiXWdUPVogOlAgK1MrQWdaIHbDeA==&input=NTIyMzAw).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 211 bytes

```perl6
{.put for map |*,zip map {.[0]X .[1].rotor: .[2..*]},zip <CIA: BANE:>,(<If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.>,<It would be extremely painful... for you!>),|(.base(2)~~m:g/(.)$0*/)».chars.rotor(2)}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>398</s> <s>390</s> <s>385</s> <s>396</s> 389 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[] a){string s="2"+System.Convert.ToString(int.Parse(a[0]),2),e="CIA: ",r="BANE: ",o="";int k=0,l=0,i=1;string[] c="If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.".Split(' '),b="It would be extremely painful... for you!".Split(' ');for(;i<s.Length;i++)o+=(s[i-1]==s[i]?" ":(i<2?"":"\n")+(s[i]>'0'?e:r))+(s[i]>'0'?c[k++]:b[l++]);System.Console.Write(o);}}
```

Launch with input number as parameter.

Ungolfed:

```
class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        string s = "2" + System.Convert.ToString(int.Parse(a[0]), 2), e = "CIA: ", r = "BANE: ", o = "";
        int k = 0, l = 0, i = 1;

        string[] c = "If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy.".Split(' '), b = "It would be extremely painful... for you!".Split(' ');
        for (; i < s.Length; i++)
            o += (s[i - 1] == s[i] ? " " : (i<2?"":"\n") + (s[i] > '0' ? e : r))
                + (s[i] > '0' ? c[k++] : b[l++]);
        System.Console.Write(o); 
    }
}
```

Back to 396 bytes because I didn't notice "no newline at the begining" rule.

Comment: Sadly, `s.Replace("1",c[k++]).Replace("0",b[l++])` doesn't replace with corresponding words. It seems, C# gets replacing string once and slaps it in places.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 204+1 = 205 bytes

Requires the `-n` flag.

```
d=[%w"It would be extremely painful... for you!",%w"If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy."]
n=%w"BANE CIA"
("%b"%$_).scan(/((.)\2*)/).map{|i,b|puts n[k=b.to_i]+': '+d[k].slice!(0,i.size)*' '}
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 198 bytes

```
while($i++<19)echo($t-$s=1&$argv[1]>>19-$i)?"
"[$i<2].($s?CIA:BANE).": ":" ",explode(0,"It0would0be0extremely0painful...0for0you!0If0I0pull0that0off0will0you0die?0You're0a0big0guy.")[$$s+++7*$t=$s];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 205 bytes

```
@t=([qw/It would be extremely painful... for you!/],[qw/If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy./]);$_=sprintf'%b',$0;print$n?'BANE':'CIA',": @{[splice$t[$n=1-$n],0,length$&]}"while s/(.)\1*//;
```

Put that into a file named 494542 and run like this:

```
perl -lX 494542
```

Tested on perl v5.22

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 401 bytes

```
(require '[clojure.string :as s])(defn f[n](let[c(map #(-(int %) 48)(Integer/toString n 2))p[(s/split"It would be extremely painful... for you!"#" ")(s/split"If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy."#" ")]a["BANE" "CIA"]](loop[i[0 0] g"" d c q 2](if(<(count d)1)g(let[b(first d)j(i b)](recur(assoc i b (inc j))(str g(if(= b q)" "(str(when(not= 2 q)"\n")(a b)": "))((p b) j))(rest d) b))))))
```

Invocation:

```
(f 522300)
```

## Ungolfed

```
(require '[clojure.string :as s])
(defn dialogue[num]
    (let [dacode (map #(- (int %) 48) (Integer/toString num 2))
          phrases [(s/split"It would be extremely painful... for you!"#" ")(s/split"If I pull that off will you die? You're a big guy."#" ")]
      actors ["BANE" "CIA"]]
      (loop [idxs [0 0] finaldial "" code dacode prevbit 2]
        (if (< (count code) 1) finaldial
            (let [bit (first code) idx (idxs bit)]
              (recur (assoc idxs bit (inc idx)) (str finaldial (if (= bit prevbit) " " (str (when (not= 2 prevbit) "\n") (actors bit) ": ")) ((phrases bit) idx)) (rest code) bit))))))
```